# Container has hibernate-core library but exception is thrown

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I added maven dependency with provided scope

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.CR1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

because container (JBoss AS7) has this dependency in path .../modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/main. So why exception is thrown? With compile (default) scope is ok.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
```

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS7 doesn't support hibernate-core 4.2.0.CR1. If you would like to use a newer version, please check this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-ReplacingthecurrentHibernate4.0.xjarswithanewerversion). If i know well JBoss AS7 support 4.0.?. But as you wrote, you can check the version unter $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/main.